# How to create arrayformula in spreadsheet for =image formula?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I want to create formula based on table as follows. I created by dragging the formula down manually.

| QR Code (A) | ID (B) |
| --- | --- |
| =image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl="&B2) | 1111 |
| =image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl="&B3 | 22222 |

I got an error when I add formula as follows =arrayformula(image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl="&B2:B))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to drag the formula down; it only needs to go in cell `A2`. Clear all cells below.

To stop the formula going down the whole sheet, use:

```
=arrayformula(if(B2:B<>"",image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl="&B2:B),))
```